# How to Setup Mailto link in IE11?

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I'm setting up a Html Form with `mailto` link. It works fine in Google Chrome and pre-populates form body in the outlook. But when I do the same in Internet Explorer 11 the Email body is not populated.[Example form is here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_mail)

Is this an Issue with IE11 settings? or Am I missing something?

Comment: http://isolani.co.uk/articles/mailto.html

Answer (score 1):

I have reproduced the problem on my side,  it seems that when we click the "Send" button to send email in IE browser, the url only contain the mailto property (without the email body), and it will not append the email body to the url. So, the email body is empty.

To solve this issue, I suggest you could collect the email information, then, encode the email (refer to the [W3's URL Encoding](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/ref_urlencode.asp)), finally, send the email. code as below:

```
<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        var eTo = encodeURI("sales@example.com"); // get the receiver 
        var eSubj = encodeURI("Submission From Quote Creator"); //get the email submit.
        var emailbody = "Please enter your contact information and message here: \n\n\nQuote:\n#17350  IFW 2-inch -$829.00\n"; //get the email body.
        var eBody = encodeURI(emailbody.replace("#","23%"));

        var email = "mailto:" + eTo + "?subject=" + eSubj + "&body=" + eBody;
        console.log(email);
        document.getElementById("sales").href = email;
    }
</script>
<a href="" id="sales">send email</a>
```